# how to check if two points are on the same line in postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis, intersection

I have extracted the geometries of all intersections and I want to find all the connections (such as intersection one is connected to intersections two, three, four, five). I was thinking about achieving this by checking if two intersections (points) are on the same LineString. Does anybody know if this is a good way to do so? Is there any functions to call to check if two points are on the same line? Thank you

Comment: All the basic information is missing. Postgres and PostGIS version, table definition, sample data , the code you tried (even if it's not working)... Update with proper information, please.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the question.  He's asking if there's an existing function to see if two points are both on the same linestring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two points (or any number of points) are in a Multipoint you
can use ST_Contains(Linestring, Multipoint) which will return true

> if and only if no points of B lie in the exterior of A,
>   and at least one point of the interior of B lies in the
>   interior of A.

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Contains.html

You will need to collect up your pairs into multipoints first, which
will be a number of multipoints proportional to n^2 if you want to test all possible pairwise sets, which could be
prohibitive.  In that case, I would generate a table matching up
points to each linestring that contains them, and then aggregating that
table grouping by linestring.

See also http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Relate.html for a more
general test of spatial relationships between objects.